# finding double limits values

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

I need a function that has  both **$\lim_{x\to 0}\Big(\lim_{y\to 0} f(x, y)\Big)$,

$\lim_{y\to 0}\Big(\lim_{x\to 0} f(x, y)\Big)$** limits are exists but not existing $\lim_{(x, y)\to (0, 0)}\ f(x, y)$ limit

this is my attempt

define $f$:$\Bbb R^2$ $\to$ $\Bbb R$

$f(x, y)= \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if x=0 or y=0} \\
1, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $

I think limit values are

$\lim_{x\to 0}\Big(\lim_{y\to 0} f(x, y)\Big)=1$,
$\lim_{y\to 0}\Big(\lim_{x\to 0} f(x, y)\Big)=1$,
$\lim_{(x, y)\to (0, 0)}\ f(x, y)$ does not exists

am I correct thanks.

Comment: kindly include your attempt.

Comment: I need just limit values only I think 0, 0, does not exists  respectively

Comment: Edit your post to include why do think those are the answer?

Comment: ok I edited thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems correct.

Another one:

Define $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ as:

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2},  & \text{if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$} \\
0, & \text{if $(x,y) = (0,0)$}
\end{cases}$$

For a fixed $x \ne 0$ we have

$$\lim_{y\to0} \left|\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right| = \lim_{y\to0} |y| \cdot \underbrace{\left|\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right|}_{\ne 0} = 0$$

so $\lim_{x\to 0} \big(\lim_{y\to 0} f(x,y)\big) = 0$. Similarly we get $\lim_{y\to 0} \big(\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,y)\big) = 0$.

However, $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y)$ does not exist:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{2x^2} = \frac12$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,2x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x^2}{x^2 + 4x^2} = \frac25$$